# How to send variables to function.php in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, cookies

I want to save cookies using onclick function in my wordpress blog. So I put this code in function.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'setting_my_first_cookie' );

function setting_my_first_cookie() {

echo $v_username;
echo "This can be echo";
setcookie('username' , 'Rajeasdasdsdh' , time()+30*24*60*60);
}
```

On index.php

```
<?php 
global $v_username;
$v_username="demo"; 
$v_value="asd";
?>

<th><a href="" onclick="setting_my_first_cookie()">Set Cookie</a></th>
```

I am retriving this cookie using this code:

```
<?php
// Accessing an individual cookie value
echo $_COOKIE["username"];
?>
```

Everything is working but I cant set that cookies using variable. I cant pass `$v_username` to function. How to do it?
I want echo or alert `$v_username` in my function `setting_my_first_cookie()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the solution for me:

I used java script to get PHP variable and set cookies using them. I added this code in *`header.php`* But its also working if we add it in *`function.php`*

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function setting_my_first_cookie(variid,variname) {
 var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (30*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = variname + "=" + variid + "; " + "expires; path=/; domain=.cinemoids.com";
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

function setting_my_first_cookie_delete(variid,variname) {
   document.cookie = variname + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.cinemoids.com';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `include_once` or `include` at your index.php

Try this code for index.php :

```
<?php 
global $v_username;
$v_username="demo"; 
$v_value="asd";
include_once('function.php')    
?>

<th><a href="" onclick= <?php setting_my_first_cookie(); ?> >Set Cookie</a></th>
```

Comment: Its not working. Can you explain me what you are trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case problem is:

This hook in which you are hooked `add_action( 'init', 'setting_my_first_cookie' );` will run your function `setting_my_first_cookie` in specific place in your application, in this case, according Codex,

> after WordPress has finished loading but before any headers are sent

So if you try to debug your application, you will see that `setting_my_first_cookie` runs before your `index.php` file.

But in general, using global variables to pass parameters to functions is not good practice.

And this function will run always, so your cookie will be set always.